What is the major product formed when you react 1,3-butadiene with HBr in the presence of both ROOR and heat?
I just had an exam where we were given 1,3-butadiene as our reactant and our major product as 1-bromo-2-butene, where we had to state what the reagent was for that particular reaction. I stated that HBr would react with our reactant in the presence of a peroxide AND heat because I completely forgot whether the product was thermodynamic or kinetic, but apparently my professor said the answer should’ve been that the reactant reacts solely with HBr in the presence of heat. He said he would look into whether or not my particular reagent would work, but I was wondering if maybe someone here could walk me through what the particular mechanism would look like for the reaction I wrote out.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/59964/addition-of-hydrogen-bromide-to-1-3-butadiene-thermodynamic-and-kinetic-control
