# Is the concept of frontier orbital interactions chiefly a kinetic concept?

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory

[Frontier molecular orbital theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frontier_molecular_orbital_theory) has proved to be an immensely useful concept. The concept of HOMO-LUMO interactions are frequently employed in detailing the mechanistic descriptions of reactions in organic chemistry. It seems to me that there are numerous examples of HOMO-LUMO interactions seem to be responsible for kinetic phenomena.

For example, secondary orbital interactions allow the [preference for the endo product](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/105023/why-diels-alder-adduct-is-exo-when-we-leave-it-for-a-while) in the Diels-Alder reaction under kinetic control.

Nucleophilicity, which is often linked to the energy of the HOMO of the nucleophile, is also often regarded as a [kinetic phenomenon](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/20061/whats-the-difference-between-a-nucleophile-and-a-base). In fact, Lewis basicity itself may even be seen as a kinetic concept. For example, we make the assertion that phosphine is a better nucleophile (and also better Lewis base) compared to ammonia because $\ce {P}$ is less electronegative than $\ce {N}$ and thus, the HOMO of $\ce {PH3}$ is thus higher in energy, compared to that of $\ce {NH3}$.

Should we thus classify frontier orbital interactions as a kinetic concept?

Comment: This apply in thermochemistry as well *once* you are under kinetic control.